# FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am currently thinking which implementation of PagerAdapter should I use.
I've got dilemmas connected to both of them. Let me show you what are these.

1# FragmentPagerAdapter

Works fine, It creates new instances of fragments when none previous instances are available and retrieves previously fragments when there's such opportunity.

I've read recently on StackOverflow that, method `PagerAdapter's` `getItem()` method is called ONLY when it need to create fragment, but - it is called over and over and I had to handle creating new instances and retrieving old ones inside this method's body.

BUT - Only few callback and life-cycle methods are called. For example I can't manage to `onSaveInstanceState` to be called. So there's no way to save fragment's state - of course I can use `SharedPreferences` or something else, but I wanted to use callback methods. Is there any way to accomplish that?

2# FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Works perfectly, saves state of every fragment that `ViewPager` holds.

<s>BUT - this `PagerAdapter` ALWAYS creates new fragment. I checked it inside constructor.</s>

Isn't that inefficient? I saw Romain Guy on Google I/O materials saying that creating new `Views` is not efficient, especially when we creating lots of `Views` like in `ListView` so we use `convertView` to retrieve existing `View` and change it for our purposes as many times as we want to. So fliping between pages is quite similar - many new `Views` - because fragment is a some kind of `View`

In both `PagerAdapters` I tried trick with Overriding `destroyItem()` method but It didn't work at all.

And here's my question.

What should I do?

Should I use `SharedPreferences` and option #1 with `FragmentPagerAdapter` or option #2 with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

Is there any possibility, that I do something wrong within these adapters, to they behave not as we expect to?

Below is my code divided into "readable" parts

PagerAdapter part #1:

```
/**
 * Adapter class to {@link WizardPager}
 */
public static class WizardCrazyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    implements OnPageChangeListener{

    public static final String tag = "android:switcher:"+R.id.pager_w+":";

    /**
     * Refernece to root activity
     */
    WizardActivity wizardActivity;

    /**
     * list of fragments
     */
    private final ArrayList<FragmentInfo> fInfos = new ArrayList<FragmentInfo>();

    private short prevPageNumber = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor of adapter
     * @param wizardActivity
     *            {@link WizardActivity} as reference to activity root
     */
    public WizardCrazyAdapter(WizardActivity wizardActivity) {
        super(wizardActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        this.wizardActivity = wizardActivity;           
    }

    static final class FragmentInfo {
        private final Class<?> _clss;
        private Bundle _args;

        public FragmentInfo(Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            _clss   =clss;
            _args   =args;
        }
    }

    public void addPage(Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
        FragmentInfo fi = new FragmentInfo(clss, args);         
        fInfos.add(fi);
    }

    /**
     * Return number of pages
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return fInfos.size();
    }
```

PagerAdapter part #2:

```
    /**
     * Searches in {@link FragmentManager} for {@link Fragment} at specified position
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    private AbstractWizardFragment getFragmentAt(int position){
        FragmentManager fm = wizardActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

        AbstractWizardFragment awf = (AbstractWizardFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(tag+position);

        return awf;         
    }

    /**
     * Return page of view pager
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /*finding existing instance of fragment*/
        AbstractWizardFragment awf = getFragmentAt(position);

        if(awf == null){
            /*creating new instance if no instance exist*/
            Log.v("WizardActivity", "creating new Fragment");
            FragmentInfo fi = fInfos.get(position);
            awf = (AbstractWizardFragment) Fragment.instantiate(wizardActivity, fi._clss.getName());
        }else{
            Log.v("WizardActivity", "found existing Fragment");
        }

        return awf;
    }
```

PagerAdapter part #3:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {
        wizardActivity.stepFragment.setCurrentStepAndChangeText(pageNumber);

        if(pageNumber != prevPageNumber){
            AbstractWizardFragment prevFragment = (AbstractWizardFragment) getItem(prevPageNumber);//TODO change if any problems
            prevFragment.onDetachedFromViewPager(wizardActivity.mForm);
        }

        AbstractWizardFragment currFragment = (AbstractWizardFragment) getItem(pageNumber);//TODO change if any problems
        currFragment.onAttachedToViewPager(wizardActivity.mForm);

        prevPageNumber = (short) pageNumber;


        Log.d("WizardActivity", "onPageSelected");
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        Log.d("WizardActivity", "instantiateItem "+arg1);
        return super.instantiateItem(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
   //           super.destroyItem(container, position, object);

        Log.v("WizardActivity", "that would be destroy");
    }
}
```

ViewPager code:

```
public class WizardPager extends ViewPager{

/**
 * Flag to check if view pager must be scrolled 
 */
protected boolean isScrollable;

/**
 * Default constructor
 * @param context {@link Context}
 */
public WizardPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    isScrollable = true;
}

/**
 * Standard constructor
 * @param context {@link Context}
 * @param attrs {@link AttributeSet}
 */
public WizardPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    isScrollable = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.isScrollable) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.isScrollable) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Enable scroll of pages
 */
public void enableScroll(){
    this.isScrollable = true;
}

/**
 * Disable scroll of pages
 */
public void disableScroll(){
    this.isScrollable = false;
}

/**
 * Check if pages can be scrolled
 * @return
 */
public boolean isScrollable(){
    return isScrollable;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I messed up in `onPageSelectedMethod` - I was forcing FragmentStatePagerAdapter to call `getItem` - which instantiates Fragment at least once - method whenever page is changed. That's why I complained about instantiating Fragment every time page is changed :)

Instead of `getItem()` I should call there my `getFragmentAt()` method, and the whole callback should look like that.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {
    wizardActivity.stepFragment.setCurrentStepAndChangeText(pageNumber);

    if(pageNumber != prevPageNumber){
        AbstractWizardFragment prevFragment = (AbstractWizardFragment) getFragmentAt(prevPageNumber);
        prevFragment.onDetachedFromViewPager(wizardActivity.mForm);
    }

    AbstractWizardFragment currFragment = (AbstractWizardFragment) getFragmentAt(pageNumber);
    currFragment.onAttachedToViewPager(wizardActivity.mForm);

    prevPageNumber = (short) pageNumber;


    Log.d("WizardActivity", "onPageSelected");
}
```

Although It works fine. There still might be risk, that `Fragment` won't be found and the method will return null - and then consequently NPE will be thrown.